# My Jasper file wont work

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to make this program but i cannot take a report out of it... even if it worked in java netbeans when i tried to run it using the executable JAR file i get this error !
my coding part is

```
        JRTableModelDataSource datasource = new JRTableModelDataSource(dt.getModel());
        String reportSource = "file/door_reports.JRXML";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("c1", subtot.getText());
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, datasource);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint1, false);
```

error is : `error compiling java source file D:/test/dist/Blank_A4_1426091490655_11644`

above file do not even exist! anybody know what would be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method, it should be useful for you:

```
 public static void GenerateReport(String filename, HashMap parameter) {
        try {
            JasperDesign jspDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(filename);
            JasperReport jspReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jspDesign);
            JasperPrint jspPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jspReport, parameter, yourconnection);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jspPrint, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

and be sure of the path of the file, good luck.

Comment: no mate.. same error occur :(its somthing with the compiled jasper file.. i found that above file name in there "Blank_A4_1426091490655_11644" i have not even created such file

Comment: Check whether all the JARS and config files are in correct location

Comment: every thing working when i run the program with netbeans... so i guss jars in the corrct location...

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename your jxml after you edited it in Jasper?
The report sets the report file name you chose while creating it in Jasper as name, so if you did simple rename your file and not change the name directly in the jxml too... i think there could be your problem.